# 範囲制限付きの数値型を作成するにはどうすればどうすればいいですか？

Tags: haskell

Haskellにて範囲を制限してくれるようなIntのような型を作ってみたいのですが、
以下のようにBounded型クラスのインスタンスにしても制限されません。
どうすれば範囲制限付きのIntのような型を作成できますか？

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Century = Century Int
   deriving (Num,Eq,Ord,Show)

instance Bounded Century where
    minBound = 0
    maxBound = 100
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Num`クラスの`fromInteger`メソッドを自前で書くこと](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html)で、 数値リテラルを使うことが出来ます。（ベースはHidekiさんの回答と同様です）

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Century (Century, makeCentury) where

newtype Century = Century Int
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

makeCentury :: Int -> Century
makeCentury n
    | n < 0 || n > 100 = error "Out of range"
    | otherwise        = Century n

instance Num Century where
  Century a + Century b = makeCentury $ a + b
  Century a * Century b = makeCentury $ a * b
  abs (Century a) = makeCentury $ abs a
  signum (Century a) = makeCentury $ signum a
  fromInteger = makeCentury . fromIntegral
  negate (Century a) = makeCentury $ negate a
```

```
*Century> 1 :: Century
Century 1
*Century> 100 :: Century
Century 100
*Century> 10 * 100 :: Century
Century *** Exception: Out of range
```

但し、このコードだとラップアラウンドを警告してくれない点に注意してください。

Answer (score 1):

一言でいうとできないのですが、型の定義をモジュールの中に隠して、その型の値を生成して返す関数をエクスポートすることで、似たようなことができます。

例えば、下のような内容の Century.hs を作成します。

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Century (makeCentury) where

newtype Century = Century Int
    deriving (Num,Eq,Ord,Show)

makeCentury :: Int -> Century
makeCentury n
    | n < 0 || n > 100 = error "Out of range"
    | otherwise        = Century n
```

これをコンパイルしてインポートすると、Century はエクスポートしていないので、データコンストラクタは使えません。

```
import Century

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ show (makeCentury 3)   -- 'Century 3' と出力
    putStrLn $ show (makeCentury 101) -- 実行時エラー
    -- putStrLn $ show (Century 1010) コンパイルできない
```

Comment: これだと`makeCentury 1 + makeCentury 100 -> Century 101`の様にチェックを迂回できてしまいますね。